# Lambda statement to project results based on if

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, c#-3.0

I have a user who is part of a company, this company can have multiple offices, so the user can be part of head/main office or part of another office, I am projecting from a lamdba expression but I cannot figure out how to do: if user is not headoffice throw out the office address.

The code below shows user, joined onto userhistory (2 table join - which is necessary so I can throw out some info that is held on that table related to this user), here is what I have done so far:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AjaxOnly]
    public PartialViewResult GetUsers(string term)
    {

        var _sf = _repo.Single<Company>(x => x.Type == x.IsActive &&
            (x.Identifier.Contains(term) || x.Name.Contains(term)));

        //get company with addresses...
        var users = _repo.All<User>().Where(x => x.CompanyID == _sf.CompanyID);
        var offices = _repo.All<Office>().Where(x => x.CompanyID == _sf.CompanyID);

        var _users = _repo.All<UserHistory>()
            .Join(users, x => x.UserID, y => y.UserID,
            (s, u) => new
            {
                _s = s,
                _user = u
            }).Select(x => new QuoteData
            {
                Login = x._user.Login,
                Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", x._user.FirstName, x._user.LastName),
                Tel = x._s.Mobile,
//let me know where user is based, if head office get me the address too...
                IsBasedInHeadOffice = x._user.IsBasedInHeadOffice

//here: if !IsBasedInHeadOffice => GetMeAddress
            });

        return PartialView("QuoteUsersUC", _users);
    }

public class QuoteData
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
    public bool IsBasedInHeadOffice { get; set; }
}
```

Could I have written this even better/ simpler?

Comment: Are the addresses also in the same database? It could be quite inefficient to fetch all the addresses one at a time in a separate query (if that is what GetMeAddress does)

Comment: Yes, same database, the address is actually - var offices = _repo.All<Office>().Where(x => x.CompanyID == _sf.CompanyID); I wrote psuedo code above to show where I was stuck, i was not showing a new function or method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
.Select(x =>
        {
            var result = new QuoteData
            {
                Login = x._user.Login,
                Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", x._user.FirstName,
                                                x._user.LastName),
                Tel = x._surveyor.Mobile,
                IsBasedInHeadOffice = x._user.IsBasedInHeadOffice
            };
            if(!result.IsBasedInHeadOffice)
                result.Address = GetMeAddress();
            return result;
        });
```

**UPDATE:**
Using LINQ2SQL or EF, this should be a lot simpler because of the so called navigation properties. Basically, they remove the need for manual joins in your C# code, if your database is properly set up with foreign keys.
For example, if your table `USER_HISTORY` would have a foreign key constraint on the column `user_id` to the table `USER`, your class `User` would have a property `UserHistories` of type `IEnumerable<UserHistory>` that contains all associated user histories and the class `UserHistory` would have a property `User`. The same is true for all other associations: User <-> Company and Company <-> Office

Using this, your code could easily be rewritten to this:

```
public PartialViewResult GetUsers(string term)
{

    var sf = _repo.Single<Company>(x => x.Type == x.IsActive &&
        (x.Identifier.Contains(term) || x.Name.Contains(term)));

    var users = 
    sf.Users
      .SelectMany(x => x.UserHistories
                        .Select(y =>
                                new QuoteData
                                {
                                    Login = x.Login,
                                    Name = string.Format("{0} {1}",
                                                         x.FirstName, 
                                                         x.LastName),
                                    Tel = y.Mobile,
                                    IsBasedInHeadOffice = x.IsBasedInHeadOffice
                                    Address = x.IsBasedInHeadOffice ? 
                                              sf.Office.Address : 
                                              string.Empty
                                }));

    return PartialView("QuoteUsersUC", _users);
}
```

Comment: I have an error with the code above:**A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree**, what does this mean?

Comment: @Haroon: you forgot to mention it is not Linq to objects? Linq to SQL or Entities requires a LINQ provider to support the expression tree

Comment: This means that you cannot use the code above, because you are using linq2sql or EF and those try to convert your code to SQL and therefore are working with expression trees... You failed to add the info that you are using L2S or EF to your question.

Comment: @Daniel - ok, so can I still achieve what I need? Sorry daniel!